# Реактивность состояния виджетов в Qt5

Tags: reactjs, vue.js, qt5

Собственно, вопрос такой: имеется ли в Qt средства для создания реактивных виджетов/компонентов как, например, в ReactJs или в Vuejs? Или это все придется все самому реализовывать?

Comment: В Qt  (да и вообще в декстопном программировании) нет той проблемы, которая есть с виджетами в вебе. Поэтому и не нужны никакие "реактивные виджеты"

Answer (score 2):

Модуль Qt Quick (QML) обширно использует реактивный подход при работе с декларативными интерфейсами - http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-syntax-propertybinding.html

К примеру, выражение `Math.min(a.width, a.height)` пересчитывается, когда изменяются `a`, `a.width` или `a.height`. "Под капотом" реализация использует свойства и сигналы Qt.

Comment: Вот, например, допустим, есть массив объектов(абстрактно) - это данные. Каждому элементу массива соответствует своя кнопка(то есть есть список кнопок) К имени кнопки привязка на к полю name элемента массива. Если к массиву прибавляется новый элемент, то количество кнопок увеличивается также и наоборот.  Меняется, напрмиер, значения поля name какого-либо элемента соответственно меняется и название кнопки. Есть подобный пример?

Comment: Я подобное делал без реактивности для примера ради. Но там при изменении поля name какого-нибудь элемента приходилось пройтись по массиву кнопок с нужным id и менять там название.

Comment: В зависимости от того, какие именно данные (массив объектов или, скорее, таблица) есть разные подходы. Это может быть `ListView` со стороны QML + модель в плюсах, если упор на таблицу скалярных данных. Либо `Repeater` со стороны QML + `QQmlListProperty` в плюсах, если хочется именно объекты передавать.

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-modelviewsdata-modelview.html - вот здесь описана работа с моделями.